# Is there a way to access a file within the www folder from another file inside the same www folder using phonegap?

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to access a text file inside the www folder of one of my phonegap applications from the index.html. I don't think filereader works because it accesses the phone's file system and not the application's file system. Regardless, here's what I tried and it jumps to the error function when this line is called within gotFS:

```
     fileSystem.root.getFile("version.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
```

Here's my full index.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
            <script charset="utf-8" src = "jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
            <script charset="utf-8" src = "cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>



<script>
 function test()
 {
     window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
 }
 function gotFS(fileSystem) {
     document.write("gotFSreached");
     fileSystem.root.getFile("version.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail); // this jumps to fail
 }

 function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
     document.write("gotFileEntryreached");
     fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
 }

 function gotFile(file){
     document.write("gotFilereached");
     readAsText(file);
 }

 function readAsText(file) {
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
         console.log("Read as text");
         document.write(evt.target.result);
     };
     reader.readAsText(file);

 }

 function fail(evt) {
     document.write("error");
 }
 </script>
<body>
<button type="button" onclick="test()">Print version.txt</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("version.txt", function(data) {
   // there u have version.txt data (in var data)
});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. I just put that code in the function that is called on the button click, then within function(data) I tried to do a document.write(data); but nothing happens.

Comment: uhm really ?, this works perfectly for me :s check the console log pls, my guess is that now you are getting some cross origin source error